# Error hacer una consulta con la funcion Ajax ayuda

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo un problema con una función, lo que estoy haciendo es un motor de búsqueda y, dentro, hay otro div que se supone que cuando hago clic en el me tiene que dar los datos del usuario pero no hacer nada

pero si lo saco el div del buscador si funciona a que se debe eso

**Este es el buscador:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('keyup', '#search', function (e) {


        e.preventDefault();
        var search = $(this).val();
  var text_trim = $.trim(search);
  
        if (text_trim == "") {
   $("#search_error_contact").hide();
            $("#result_Search_contact").hide();
            $("#search_input_clean").hide();
            $("#contact_list_user").show();
        } else {
   $('#result_Search_contact').html('<center><img class="loader_data_img_ajax" src=" " alt="" /></center>');
   $("#search_error_contact").hide();
            $.ajax({
                url: Ajax_Requests_File(),
                type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
                data: 'search=' + search,
                beforeSend: function () {

                    $('#searcbtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    $("#contact_list_user").hide();
                    $("#search_input_clean").show();
                    $("#result_Search_contact").html(data).show();
                    
                    $('#searcbtn').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
     if(data!=""){
      $('#result_Search_contact').html(data);
     }
                },
                error: function(){
                   $("#search_error_contact").show();
             
                }
            });
        }

    });

});
```

**Este es el codigo ajax que tiene el div con el contenido:**

```js
 $('.wall_chat_users').on('click', function(){
  
  $('#add_chats_users').html('<center><img class="po_add_chat loader_data_img_ajax" src=" " alt="" /></center>');  
  var data_id = $(this).data('id');
  $.ajax({
   url: Ajax_Requests_File(),
   type: 'POST',
   cache: false,
   data: 'add_chat_user='+ data_id,
   success: function(data){
    $("#add_chats_users").html(data);//$('#more-info').html(data.html);
    if(data!=""){
     $('#add_chats_users').html(data);
    }
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    $('#add_chats_users').html('<center><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-uinvert-dock/128/Wifi_Not_Connected.png"/></center>');             
   }
  });
 });
```

Comment: te fijaste que no tengan los mismo id?

Comment: No es con respecto a tu pregunta, pero como consejo si estas urtilizando html5 NO uses etiquetas obsoletas como `<center>` si tu pagina estará en internet algunos motores de búsqueda como google te castigan si en tu dom declaras `<!Doctype html>` y usas etiquetas obsoletas. Haciendo que pegue muy fuerte en el SEO Saludos.

Comment: En todo el código que has compartido no veo ni un solo `div`...

Comment: @vcasas ok gracias por el consejo no lo sabia :)

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez no el ID es unico

Comment: @A.Cedano es un decir ya que el ID este dentro del DIV y a la vez esta la funcion ajax no tiene una idea de por que pasa esto?